# Remove windows security authentication screen when using 'edit in Microsoft Office' feature in Alfresco

Tags: windows-7, ms-office, alfresco, alfresco-share, windows-security

I am using Alfresco-5.1, MS-Office 2013 and Windows-7. I have done the Alfresco setup in my system and uploaded few documents. To edit the documents, I want to use the 'Edit in Microsoft Office' feature, but when I click on it, I am getting the windows security popup window screen as shown below and it ask for username and password again. I want to remove this popup window. How can I remove it ?

[image: Windows Security Pop-up Window]

Comment: Setup a SSO that's available to both IE and Office, eg Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: I am using CAS SSO authentication for Alfresco.

Comment: Does Microsoft Office 2013 support CAS? If not, you'd need to switch to something it does, eg Kerberos or NTLM

Answer (score 2):

For Office 2013 you needed to add your server to AuthForwardServerList as explained here (WebDAV): https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/auth-kerberos-clientconfig.html

For Office 2016 you need to disable modern authentication in Office by setting EnableADAL to 0.as explained here: https://blog.littleimpact.de/2018/09/22/alfresco-kerberos-and-office-2016-credential-pop-ups/

Comment: nice finding for EnableADAL. Thanks for your hint and your blog post!

Comment: For a webdav client in PHP we solved the ADAL problem serverside with header manipulation, no client side disabling needed. `SetEnvIf Authorization ^Bearer$ disable_adal=1` `Header set WWW-Authenticate Negotiate env=disable_adal`